# Discord.py on_member_update not working, members intent enabled

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this thing I coded using the on_member_update event to make it so my bot will kick a member in my server that has no roles and goes offline, as well as DMing them. When I do this code, it does nothing and doesn't even raise an error.

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if before.status != after.status:
        if len(after.roles) == 0:
            if str(after.status) == "offline":    
                reason = "Went offline without verifying"
                dmkickembed = discord.Embed(title = "Reason: " + reason, description = "_ _", color = 0x2F3136)
                dmkickembed.set_author(name = f"You have been kicked from server.", icon_url = f"{bot.user.avatar_url}")
                dmkickembed.add_field(name = "Come back with this link:", value = "link")
                try:
                    # send to member
                    await after.send(embed = dmkickembed)
                except discord.HTTPException:
                    pass
                # kick here
                await after.kick(reason=reason)
```

I even tried having the first line inside the event printing str(after.status). Still does absolutely nothing. Just so you know, yes I have the members intent enabled both in the code and in Discord Dev Portal.

Here is how I enabled my intents:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=["m/", "M/"], status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name="Loading...", intents=intents))
```

Comment: Try `if after.status == discord.Status.offline`

Comment: That doesn't work, because the event itself is not triggering.

Comment: Oh i see, thats weird, is the rest of your code working? Is the bot connecting properly?

Comment: The rest of the code in the bot seems to be working, and it has no problem connecting.

Comment: Found your issue, i think, change line 4 to `if len(after.role) == 1`, @everyone is always the first element of the roles liist

Comment: It still doesn't work, because things even after line 2 don't execute. Is there a way I can get the event to actually trigger? It lives near the top of my file, before all of the commands. There are two events before it, which are on_command_error and on_message.

Comment: Damn, honestly I have no clue, sorry, all of the code you have displayed there at least should trigger the event

Comment: Odd. I just tested it and I can't get an `on_member_update` event to fire either. This might be a bug.

Comment: Did you enable intents?

Comment: This isn't a bug, `on_member_update` event needs `presences` intents and not `members` https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.presences (at least `.status` and `.activities` attributes do need it) also are you sure you have enabled intents in your code as well? if so, could you edit your code to show how you have enabled it?

Comment: I edited it. Did I enable them right?

Comment: @Deseptor so you already had both `members` *and* `precenses` enabled originally, and it still wasn't working?

Comment: I did, and I even tried all intents but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong event.

Use **on_presence_update()** for status and activity changes